# How to change the show grub boot menu hotkey

Tags: grub2

I have a laptop that other people use and I want to use Linux, but I don't want the other users to see the Linux partition and only see the windows partition. I already know it's possible to hide the grub boot menu unless a hotkey is pressed.

Is it possible to change the hotkey that will open it (or disable it altogether?)

Note: I am using Zorin OS 15 Core (An ubuntu-based OS).

Edit 1: I am worried, as they're known for getting viruses, so they always boot into recovery mode a lot, so they might stumble across it while they're trying to get into the bios or they're holding down right-shift instead of shift to get into recovery mode.

Edit 2: I also know grub has password protection, and I will be using that, but I still don't want them to ever know that the Linux partition is there.

Comment: how would people see the linux partition if they do not start up linux?

Comment: I just added an edit clarifying why.

Comment: i think that grub allows password protection